# Alert for Azure Virtual Machine running for X hours?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, alert, cost-management

I use an Azure VM for personal purposes and use it mostly like I would use a laptop for checking email etc. However, I have several times forgot to stop the VM when I am done using it and thus have had it run idle for days, if not weeks, resulting in unnecessarily high billing.

I want to set up an email (and if possible also SMS and push notification) alert.

I have looked at the alert function in the advisor, but it does not seem to have enough customization to handle such a specific alert (which would also reduce Microsoft's income!).

Do you know any relatively simple way to set up such an alert?

Comment: Sure, just please let me check that I can make it work first. Life's pretty busy now but my Azure bills are also easy too high so I will get to it soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take use of  [Log Analytics workspaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm) and [Custom log search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal).

The below are the steps to create an alert, which will send the alert if the azure vm is running exactly 1 hour.

First:

you need to create a `Log Analytics workspaces` and `connect to azure vm` as per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-azurevm).

Sencod:

1.In azure portal, nav to `Azure Monitor` -> `Alerts` -> `New alert rule`.

2.In the "Create rule" page, for `Resource`, select the `Log Analytics workspaces` you created ealier. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Then for `Condition`, please select `Custom log search`. Screenshot as below:

[image]

Then in the `Configure signal logic` page, in `Search query`, input the following query:

```
Heartbeat
| where Computer == "yangtestvm" //this is your azure vm name
| order by TimeGenerated desc
```

For `Alert logic`: set `Based on` as `Number of results`, set `Operator` as `Equal to`, set `Threshold value` as `60`.

For `Evaluated based on`: set `Period` as `60`, set Frequency as `5`.

The screenshot as below:

[image]

**Note**:

for the above settings, I query the **Heartbeat** table. For `azure vm` which is running, it always sends data to log analytics to the **Heartbeat** table **per minute**. So if I want to check if the azure vm is running exactly 1 hour(means it sends 60 data to Heartbeat table), just use the above query, and set the **Threshold value** to **60**.

Another thing is the **Period**, it also needs to be set as 1 hour(60 minutes) since I just check if the azure vm is running for 1 hour; for **Frequecy**, you can set it any value you like.

If you understand what I explains, you can change these values as per your need.

At last, set the other settings for this alert.

Please let me know if you still have more issues about this.

Comment: Hi Ivan and thank you so much for the response. It is not working at the moment but I think it is because there is some nuance I have not picked up on. For example, in the alert rule, the action is a bit unclear to me. I have an action group set with the resource to the same VM I have used for the alert and log analytics workspace.

Comment: Is the above correct? Further, in the link you referred to for the Log Analytics Workspace, under the heading "Data collection from Windows VM" I am a bit unsure about how to set it up. Especially what counters to include. I have:

Heartbeat | where OSType == 'Windows' | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SourceComputerId | top 500000 by Computer asc | render table

I just saw "Heartbeat", recognized the name and picked that one but perhaps this is wrong?

Comment: Actually I got it to work now, I fiddled around a bit with the alert query. I ended up with: // List heartbeats
// List all computer heartbeats from the last2 hours
Heartbeat 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2h)
And then I am plaing around with the various timings and periods to make the alert as useful as possible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Azure Activity log to determine if a VM has been running for more than a specified amount of time. The benefit to this approach is that you don't need to enable Diagnostic Logging (Log Analytics), it also supports appliances that can't have an agent installed (i.e. NVAs).

The logic behind this query is to determine if the VM is in a running state, and if so has it been running for more than a specified period of time (MaxUpTime).

This is achieved by getting the most recent event of type 'Start' or 'Deallocate', then checking if this event is of type 'Start' and was generated more than 'MaxUpTime' ago

```
let DaysOfLogsToCheck = ago(7days);
let MaxUptime = ago(2h); // If the VM has been up for this long we want to know about it
AzureActivity
| where TimeGenerated > DaysOfLogsToCheck
// ActivityStatus == "Succeeded" makes more sense, but in practice it can be out of order, so "Started" is better in the real world
| where OperationName in ("Deallocate Virtual Machine", "Start Virtual Machine") and ActivityStatus == "Started"
// We need to keep only the most recent entry of type 'Deallocate Virtual Machine' or 'Start Virtual Machine'
| top 1 by TimeGenerated desc
// Check if the most recent entry was "Start Virtual Machine" and is older than MaxUpTime
| where OperationName == "Start Virtual Machine" and TimeGenerated <= MaxUptime
| project TimeGenerated, Resource, OperationName, ActivityStatus, ResourceId
```